# Characterization of nonseparable graphs of which the complements are also nonseparable graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

My question is pretty much all contained in the title. Other than just drawing both the graph and its complement, are there simpler characterizations of such graphs? Say via degree sequence or what have you? So far I only know as an empirical fact that such graphs only exist for number of vertices $V\geq 5$.

Comment: What is a nonseparable graph?

Comment: For a moment I thought you might be using "nonseparable graph" to mean "$2$-connected graph" but that can't be right because the cycle graph $C_5$ is a $2$-connected graph with a $2$-connected complement, but it has only $5$ vertices.

Comment: @bof, I mean 2-connected. You are absolutely right, I forgot about $C_5$ because for my particular study all $C_n$ are considered trivial. I corrected the question.